# Bootstrap reduce spacing between columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Having an issue reducing the amount of spacing between buttons in the same row. These buttons are wrapped in columns
[image: Spacing issue buttons]
[JSFiddle](https://jsbin.com/xowejaweku/edit?html,output)

Is there an easy way to do this? I imagine using negative margins or padding is not necessarily desirable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the padding not the margin. This piece of css removes the white space between the columns

```
   .form-group .col-xs-6{
      padding: 0px;
    }
```

Comment: definitely padding

Comment: Ah, it was indeed the padding. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In **Bootstrap 4**, you **don't need the extra CSS**. Just use the spacing utils (`p-*`) or the `no-gutters` class...

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block">Test One
                <br>Some More</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block">Test Two
                <br>Some More)</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 pr-1">
            <button class="btn btn-block">Test Three
                <br>Some More</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 pl-1">
            <button class="btn btn-block">Test Four
                <br>Some More</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/AjLhoAztxt